# How to look for child elements in a collection

Tags: javascript, html

im very new to javascript and probably thats a silly question. What I am trying to achieve is to loop through rows of a "table", get the innerHTML of specific child nodes and multiply them together.

The html looks like this:

```html
<div class="parent">
    ...
    <div class="countChild">
        <div class="container">
            <span class="count">5</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="valueChild">
        <span class="value">30</span>
    </div>
    ...
</div>
<div class="parent">
    ...
    <div class="countChild">
        <div class="container">
            <span class="count">2</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="valueChild">
        <span class="value">30</span>
    </div>
    ...
</div>
```

To be specific: I want to get both the values inside the'countChild' and the 'valueChild'. In this example those are 5 and 30 for the first row and for the second row its 2 and 30. Then perform a muiltiplication.

What I tried to do is to get all the parent nodes and then iterating through them to get the child nodes.

```js
const parents = document.getElementsByClassName('parent');
for(var row in parents) {
 var count = row.getElementsByClassName('countChild').lastChild.innerHTML;
 var value = row.getElementsByClassName('valueChild').lastChild.innerHTML;
  ....
}
```

However the debugger already throws an error when im trying to get the childs. The error message is *row.getElemenstByClassName is not a function*. I guess the collection cannot be used like this and my understanding of how to use js to get information from the document is wrong.

Edit: This is what the tree looks like

```html
<div class="listing-entry">
  <div class="value-container d-none d-md-flex justify-content-end">
    <div class="d-flex flex-column">
      <div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-end">
        <span class="font-weight-bold color-primary small text-right text-nowrap">30</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="count-container d-none d-md-flex justify-content-end mr-3">
    <span class="item-count small text-right">5</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should access `parents` like an array (not really array but you can cast it to one). Btw, I encourage you to use `querySelectorAll` and `querySelector` instead of `getElementsByClassName`

```js
const parents = document.querySelectorAll(".parent")
parents.forEach(function(row) {
  var countChild = row.querySelector(".countChild")
  var valueChild = row.querySelector(".valueChild")
  var count = countChild ? countChild.innerText : 0
  var value = valueChild ? valueChild.innerText : 0
  console.log(count, value, count * value)
})
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  ...
  <div class="countChild">
    <div class="container">
      <span class="count">5</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="valueChild">
    <span class="value">30</span>
  </div>
  ...
</div>
<div class="parent">
  ...
  <div class="countChild">
    <div class="container">
      <span class="count">2</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="valueChild">
    <span class="value">30</span>
  </div>
  ...
</div>
```

Edit: I'm using querySelector instead of getElementsByClassName, and checking if child exists before accessing its innerText property.

Edit: here's a function to get all text nodes under a specific node. Then you can combine them and trim the result to get the value you want.

```js
function textNodesUnder(node) {
  var all = [];
  for (node = node.firstChild; node; node = node.nextSibling) {
    if (node.nodeType == 3) {
      all.push(node);
    } else {
      all = all.concat(this.textNodesUnder(node));
    }
  }
  return all;
}

var nodes = textNodesUnder(document.querySelector(".listing-entry"))
var texts = nodes.map(item => item.nodeValue.trim())
console.log(texts)
```

```html
<div class="listing-entry">
  <div class="value-container d-none d-md-flex justify-content-end">
    <div class="d-flex flex-column">
      <div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-end">
        <span class="font-weight-bold color-primary small text-right text-nowrap">30</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="count-container d-none d-md-flex justify-content-end mr-3">
    <span class="item-count small text-right">5</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks it works getting both child nodes with their own childs. But it does not work indexing those with [0]. Your lines, 3,4 and 5 do work without the [0].innerText at the end. Otherwise an error gets thrown TypeError: row.getElementsByClassName(...)[0] is undefined.
I still have the problem that those nodes do not contain the text. Instead some n-th children contains it. So what I tried is
while(count.childElementCount > 0) { count = count.children[0]; } but this does not seems to change anything. count seems to still reference the same node when it was assigned using the query.

Comment: when you have the undefined error it's because there are no elements matching the class `countChild` or `valueChild`. check length before you access `[0]`. once you do get an element, getting its `innerText` should be fine regardless of position of that text node inside it

Comment: Im a bit confused about this. i do not think that countChild and valueChild are undefined. If i remove the indexing stuff "[0].innerText" during the assignment of the vars, then im able to log the nodes and see all of their properties and also the child nodes in the console.

Comment: can you add the html (part) that fails to work?

Comment: I edited the post. So the tree looks like in my simplification I just omitted the long class names.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts. I used your updated code, but it still does not seem to work to get the innerText. I can log the nodes with their sub-tree but not the innerText. If i try to log count or value then the output is: undefined, undefined, NaN.

Comment: Now finally! Your first method works, all of a suddden. I had a typo in the countChild and valueChild line. I was using querySelectorAll for those. Would be great if you could explain why using querySelector all does not work. Even though the nodes seem to be the same. The only difference in the console is that they are of nodelist type instead of the plain html <div>. Also why did the first method using getElementsByClassName + indexing not work for the count and value nodes?

Comment: glad it worked. maybe the first method with `getElementsByClassName` does work if you fix the typo. you can read more about [Element.querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll)

Comment: I read through it and also through the nodelist struct, but still dont understand why using a nodelist did not work at all. Even using the loop mentioned above to get to the last child node, did not change anything.